# What happens internally when the outermost Stream is closed?

Tags: java

I know that to close all the internal and enclosing streams you can close the outermost Stream and it will take care of the enclosing Streams but do it waits to read and write data completely before closing the internal streams or just perform the required operations.

I just want to figure out what happens and how internal functions are called on the inner streams when we close an enclosing Stream? Just like in the below code

```
 public static void serialize(Object obj, String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    bos.flush();
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.close();
 }
```

When I close the Object Stream will it wait for File Stream to perform its function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you close the ObjectOutputStream, all pending write operations will be performed.
That is because ObjectOutputStream calls `innerStream.flush()` wenn you call `close()` on it.
And BufferedOutputStream also calls `innerStream.flush()` in its own flush method.

All buffering stream classes I know do so.